# gitHub - Committing and Pushing Dev Branch Pushed to Another Branch

Tags: github, push, git-branch

I have a dev branch. I made local changes, committed them `git commit -m "blah" file` and pushed these changes to my branch(ccap-biology-dev) `git push origin ccap-biology-dev`
. These changes were committed another branch(ccap-biology) as well as some temp files that my .gitignore file handles. None of these temp files are on my branch. I would like to avoid this from happening again. However, I do not know what I did incorrectly or the best way to correct this.

Steps I've taken to attempt to isolate the problem:

```
1. git remote -v:
   origin   https://github.com/Connexions/oer.exports.git (fetch)
   origin   https://github.com/Connexions/oer.exports.git (push)</code>

2. git branch -avvv
   ccap-biology                           0105488 [origin/ccap-biology] Update css/ccap-numbering.less
 * ccap-biology-dev                       c674100 module2epub
   remotes/origin/HEAD                     -> origin/master
   remotes/origin/ccap-biology             0105488 Update css/ccap-numbering.less
   remotes/origin/ccap-biology-dev         c674100 module2epub
   remotes/origin/master                   fa3d5fa Added some styling to solutions

3. branch log file doesn't reflect a commit on ccap-biology
4. gitHub Activity Feed does not show this push either
```

This happen during commit `c674100 module2epub`. What are the next steps to take to find out what happened? What is the best way to cleanup the branch that I accidentally pushed to?

Any help appreciated. Thanks ahead of time.